# No route matches {:action=>"show" ... missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

Seeing many question related to this but none of them gives answer to my problem.
I have Rails api application without ActiveRecord support. It is easy to reproduce problem. Follow steps:
Create rails api site without ActiveRecord support

```
rails new test001 -O --api
```

Change folder to test001 and run:

```
rails g scaffold testapp id name
```

Create model file **testapp.rb** in app/models folder

```
class Testapp
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :created_at, :updated_at
  def self.all
    t1 = Testapp.new(:id =>111, name: "t111")
    return [t1]
  end
end
```

Start server

```
rails s
```

Using postman REST client create GET request

```
http://localhost:3000/testapps.json
```

It fails with error `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"testapps", :format=>:json, :id=>#<Testapp:0x00000005411518 @id=111, @name="t111">} missing required keys: [:id]):`

I have dummy implementation for POST, PUT, GET 1 item and all works. Here is dummy implementation of GET 1 item (/testapps/x.json)

```
  def self.find(p)
    return Testapp.new(:id =>p, name: "t123")
  end
```

What is the problem with GET all (/testapps.json)?

Comment: In order to verify a possible answer, it would be helpful if you could post your `routes.rb` file, or the specific part of that file wherein you set the routes up for your `testapps` controller.

Comment: `Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :testapps
end`
As I said, all other works.

Comment: @craig.kaminsky
You can download application from [dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10850412/test001.zip)

Answer (score 2):

Found solution.
Problem is scaffold generated **index.json.jbuilder**
file:

```
json.array!(@testapps) do |testapp|
  json.extract! testapp, :id, :id, :name
  json.url testapp_url(testapp, format: :json) #REMOVE
end
```

It added line **json.url testapp_url(testapp, format: :json)** for no reason. **json.extract!** deserialized object already.
Removing line solved problem.
I still do not know why testapp_url(testapp, format:json) caused error. Checking Rails Routing document http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html